# eomonth operand type clash (Msg 2016)

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime-format

```
DECLARE @DateMin AS date = DATEFROMPARTS(2019, 7, 19);
DECLARE @DateTimeMax AS datetime = EOMONTH(@DateMin)+1;
```

Error Messages:

> Msg 2016, Level 16.
>   operand type clash. date is incompatible with int.

Error happens on the second line.
Using SQL Server 2016.

Comment: [21 questions, never an accepted solution](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3046585/ludovic-aubert?tab=questions). Please do show your appreciation to those taking their *free* time to help you by marking answers as solutions when they sovle the problem; plus it means that future readers know the problem was solved and the answer is helpful.

Comment: fair enough. I got interrupted and will do that monday, after sorting out the answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server, you can add a number to a `datetime` to add days, but not to a `date`.  So, you could fix this in two ways if you insist on this construct:

```
DECLARE @DateMin datetime = DATEFROMPARTS(2019, 7, 19);
-----------------^ change type to datetime
DECLARE @DateTimeMax datetime = DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(@DateMin));
```

Or:

```
DECLARE @DateMin date = DATEFROMPARTS(2019, 7, 19);
DECLARE @DateTimeMax datetime = CONVERT(datetime, DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(@DateMin)));
--------------------------------^ add explicit conversion
```

I do think that `dateadd(day, )` is a better solution because the intent is clearer.

Answer (score 4):

The error is telling you the problem, `date` and `int` are incompatible. Use `DATEADD`:

```
DECLARE @DateMin AS date = DATEFROMPARTS(2019, 7, 19);
DECLARE @DateTimeMax AS datetime = DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(@DateMin));
```